# Disable Lazy Loading for Featured Image in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, lazy-loading

Is there a way to disable Lazy Loading of the Featured Image in Wordpress?

Currently, I am using the [Lazy Load plugin from WPRocket](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rocket-lazy-load/) which works well, but it also lazy loads the Featured Image which causes a long LCP.

Comment: https://docs.wp-rocket.me/article/15-disabling-lazy-load-on-specific-images

Comment: Use this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-lazy-load/

Comment: @MattHamer5, The Lazy Load plugin does not have any settings. It's not the full WPRocket plugin. 

SavanDholu - I tried it, but it doesn't work. 

I only want to ensure that the first image is loaded correctly

Answer (score -1):

yes you can exclude feature images from load lazy.
go wprocket setting and then go to media section . then Excluded images or iframes section. and enter the name of feature images.
example.images.jpeg

Comment: i did that but it doesn't do anything to featured imge